# Insert to table from another table with procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables in one database

1. tbl_base
2. tbl_Rank

with this structure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Rank]
(
    [Name] [VARCHAR](17) NULL,
    [Lv] [INT] NULL,
    [ExpLeague] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [Rank] [VARCHAR](25) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_League] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_League_ExpLeague] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ExpLeague]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_League] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_League_Rank] DEFAULT ('Bronze III') FOR [Rank]
GO
```

`tbl_rank` is created with my own idea, I want to grab some data from `tbl_base` with conditions, then auto insert into `tbl_rank`.

I grab 2 columns of data from `tbl_base`: `NameCharacter` and `Level`.

If Level > 39, it will insert into `tbl_Rank` from procedure.

How to do it.?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to provide a lot more detail here before anybody can really help. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Where it the table you are trying to query? Where is the sample data? And just a suggestion, I would drop those tbl_ prefixes. The do nothing but make it harder for you to work with. And be careful using float, it is an approximate datatype. It seems like perhaps an int might be a better choice there. Or numeric.

Comment: And your constraint are on a different table...maybe changed the table for your question but not the constraints?

Comment: as i said, i just want to grab 2 data from tbl_base is Name and Lv, then insert into tbl_rank to Name and Lv Column with Procedure if Lv in tbl_base more than 39

Comment: Since you won't provide details about all I can say is use a where clause. Something like "where Lv > 39"

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your insert might look like this. But the details are elusive here.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Rank
(
    Name
    , Lv    
)
SELECT
    b.Name
    , b.Lv
FROM tbl_base b
where b.Lv > 39
```

Comment: i tried this with normal query and execute,. it work. but when i applied to procedure, theres no insert to tbl_rank

Comment: I give up. I can't see your screen and you continue to refuse to provide any real details. Good luck.